# How to add toggle button to the right toolbar?

Tags: android, toolbar

I am trying to get my toggle button to rest on my toolbar. I am not able to integrate them both because I am getting the error when I use SetSupportActionToolbar. This is my main activity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
//        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbarid);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.AddFragment(new PeopleTab(), "People");
        adapter.AddFragment(new EventsTab(), "Events");


        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
//        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(TabActivity.this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
```

This is the layout for activity:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    tools:context=".TabActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    <include
        layout="@layout/activity_navigation"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is activity_navigation that I specified :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="@string/people" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="@string/ev" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />
```

I want the output like this:

[My desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PH9cL.jpg)

I am getting the output:

[Output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ridiu.jpg)

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<style name="ButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: There is no error. I just want a different output. See images given.

Comment: make sure your apptheme is extending from NoActionBar theme. post your styles.xml code.

Comment: i think your error is your toggle button is not placed at the right position because you are using action bar theme make your own action bar to correct this and change theme of no action bar.OR see the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcnT-3F-9JA it is a tutorial for viewpager

Comment: Change `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to  `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`